# VK API нету user_id при авторизации

Tags: vkontakte-api

Делаю авторизацию с вк.

Кто подскажет в чём проблема? сервер переходит по следующему URL:
`http://oauth.vk.com/access_token?client_id=4368157&client_secret=xxxxxxxxx&code=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:3000/users/auth/&grant_type=client_credentials`

в ответ получаю JSON:
`{"access_token":"6xxxxxx55303f5650c4d2c0b6511a4e866553655303f536xxxxx39ebdec18e0","expires_in":0}`

вот ток в документации в примере, там должен быть user_id, что не так?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С `grant_type=client_credentials` вы авторизуете не юзера, а [сервер приложений](https://vk.com/dev/auth_server), так что все как в документации.

Comment: @sergiks а как получить ID юзера?

UPD
Убрал grant_type и всё получилось ;) Большое спасибо)